# How best to store/access/manipulate a very long string with numerous double quotes in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a 70KB email body (HTML) with 100s of double quotes. I need to replace small parts of it with eg a persons name, age etc. (I have placeholders for those items.)

I do not want to store it in a nvarchar(max) field in SQL Server DB as that would mean it needs to be accessed every time an email is sent which may be many times a second and the DB is on another server. I do not want to read it into memory when the web app starts as I would like the ability to change the body every now and then without stoping the site.

Perhaps I just use a plain text file that is located in the app's file structure and read it for every email. That way I can change it's contents at will.

Also will the double quotes cause a problem if I instantiate a stringbuilder whose contents are this file. I was hoping to use its Replace method to replace the placeholders.

Comment: [Regex?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Can you please provide the sample string?

Comment: Maybe even better if it's in HTML use [XSL](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307322). Should work for HTML as well. It is designed for this purpose.

Comment: What is your question? You can just a file and StringBuilder (of which I fail to see the need) can handle strings containing double quotes just fine. One of the benefits of using a file is that the disk and OS will do the caching for you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what your content string means, it is a kind of generic template for your actual emails. You will eventually change this template, so it must be up to date everytime you access it, but you do not want to fetch it anytime you need it to avoir dababase round trips.

Well this has a name, it is "**Caching**". You may have various ways to implement that, but the easiest would be to store it at application's level, and retrieve it using a **lazy loading accessor**. Simply delete this cache everytime you update your template, and optionnaly make a dummy call to the accessor so that this cache data is rebuilt.

The **StringBuilder** will handle double quotes without any issue. If you read your content string from a file, or anything that do not require a litteral initialization, your double quotes will be internally escaped bu the StringBuilder.

If you do not require to provide an UI for users to update the template, you should probably use .Net resources mechanism (resx files).

Simple example :

```
public static class EmailHelper
{
    private static string _templateString;
    private const string APP_KEY = "EmailTemplate";

    public static string TemplateString
    {
        get
        {
            // Lazy loading pattern at Application's level
            if (_templateString == null)
            {
                // if also null, fetch from your persistance layer
                if (Application[APP_KEY] == null)
                {
                    var template = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\Delete Anytime\EmailBody.txt");
                    Application[APP_KEY] = template;
                    _templateString = template;
                }
            }
            return _templateString;
        }
        set
        {           
            // value should come from reading your text file
            Application[APP_KEY] = value;
            // cache invalidation
            _templateString = null;
        }
    }

    public static string ResolvePlaceholders(Dictionnary<string, string> keyValuePairs)
    {
        // initiate a string builder from the template
        var contentBuilder = new StringBuilder(TemplateString);
        // dictionnary keys are your placeholders
        // values are actual content
        foreach(var kvp in keyValuePairs)
        {
            contentBuilder.Replace(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
        }
        return contentBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: The random bolding of parts doesn't really make your answer more readable. Also, can you explain what you mean by "lazy loading accessor", as it's kind of a vague statement, and explain how you would "simply" do cache invalidation?

Comment: I think that bolding highlights the key points to my answer. Since neither the question nor the answer have code examples, I feel it makes it more readable. You make a point for invalidation examples.

Comment: Emphasis is to be used sparingly, not applied to half of your answer.

Comment: Thanks for clearing them !

Answer (score 1):

Why not combine storing the body in a database AND having it in memory. You can even add a column in the table which stores a revision number, so you can detect changes fairly cheap. Storing it in a file localy will make keeping things in sync more difficult/prone to errors when for example you have a second web server. I dont see Why double quotes would be a problem

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all and I will digest the suggestions over time. For the moment I will go with a simple solution that worked much to my surprise as I am new to C# and most new things I try do not work.

string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Temp\Delete Anytime\EmailBody.txt");

StringBuilder emailBody = new StringBuilder(text);

emailBody.Replace("[Name]", "Any Name");